# Convert a string of strings of numbers into words like the old phones

Tags: string, list, haskell

Basically i have a list of lists made of strings that are only numbers like ["22","333","2"] and i want to transform it into the string "bea". Think of this like the old phones if u press 2 twice you get a b, if you press 4 once you get a j, like that. Only can use prelude functions

I tried it like this

```
numbers ws [] = ws
numbers ws (x:xs) = if head "2ABC" == head x
                    then ws ++ "2ABC" !! length x ++ numbers ws xs
                    else if head "3DEF" == head x
                    then ws ++ "3DEF" !! length x ++ numbers ws xs
....
```

But this gives me errors so can you help me guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Willem beat me to it but here's what I came up with. You might want to complete the keyboard though

```
numToChar :: Char -> Int -> Char
numToChar '2' i = "abc" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '3' i = "def" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '4' i = "ghi" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '5' i = "jkl" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '6' i = "mno" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '7' i = "pqrs" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '8' i = "tuv" !! (i - 1)
numToChar '9' i = "wxyz" !! (i - 1)

numbers n = [numToChar (head x) (length x) | x <- n]
```

Answer (score 5):

A classic mistake is to implement *too* much logic into a single function. Instead of trying to do the entire decoding into the `numbers` function, it might be better to split up the tasks in reusable components, such that these are easy to understand, debug, and reuse.

Here as first function, we can map the digit to a `String` containing the characters, like:

```
digtoseq :: Char -> String
digtoseq '2' = "abc"
digtoseq '3' = "def"
digtoseq '4' = "ghi"
digtoseq '5' = "jkl"
digtoseq '6' = "mno"
digtoseq '7' = "pqrs"
digtoseq '8' = "tuv"
digtoseq '9' = "wxyz"
digtoseq '0' = " "
```

We here can add extra characters, for example the `'.'` to specify the sequence behind each phone key.

Now we can implement a function that makes use of `digtoseq`, for example `digstrtoseq`:

```
digstrtoseq :: String -> Char
digstrtoseq (x:xs) = digtoseq x !! length xs
```

here we thus take the length of the string, as well as the first character, and we move through the string of `digtoseq x`, to obtain the `n-1`-th element (with `n` the length of the input string). So for `"22"`, we get:

```
Prelude> digstrtoseq "22"
'b'
Prelude> digstrtoseq "33"
'e'
Prelude> digstrtoseq "2"
'a'
```

so now it is only a matter of `map`ping this function over the string of input:

```
numbers :: [String] -> String
numbers = map digstrtoseq
```

and then we obtain:

```
Prelude> numbers ["22", "33", "2"]
"bea"
```

Note that here we made some assumptions, some of these can be improved by rewriting the functions, other are better solved by changing the type of the input:

1. we assume that no string has a length larger than the length of the sequence behind it, so `"2222"` will not occur;
2. we assume that the character in the string element is repeated over the entire string, so `"231"` will not occur;
3. we assume that the strings contain only valid digits, so no `"~"`;
4. we assume that each string contains at least one character, so no `""`.

A large amount of the assumptions originate from the fact that we here use `[String]` as input type, which gives a lot of freedom. Yes it is possible to raise errors, or to return `Nothing` in that case, but it might be better to define a type like:

```
data Key = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Zero
```

and then as input take `[(Key, Int)]`, since then assumptions (2) and (3) are simply "guaranteed" through the input type.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed more direct methods of translation or mapping. The ASCII character set can be exploited for such. This function is robust. The only limitation I can see is the length of the ASCII character set. The assumption is what we cannot type what will not be used. The first digit matters only. Anything can be used after it.

```
td=\(s:sx)->[toEnum (47+d+e+(length sx))::Char|d<-[fromEnum s],e<-[2*(mod d 50) + if d > 55 then 1 else 0]]
```

Use td any way you want.

```
concat $ map td ["222","33","9999","4"]
```

"cezg"